# C Integer losing its constant status when being used in C++ code

Tags: c++

I have a C/C++ mixed project that I am currently working on. I have a global constants C code that I want to be able to access from my C++ scripts and C scripts. In this particular situation I am trying to use a C++ array with variable dimensions made up of constant integers defined in the C global constants code. However, when I try to use or declare this array I get the error that the array dimensions are not integer constants (though I defined them to be integer constants in my C code).

constants.c

```
const int x = 5;
```

constants.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern const int x;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

my_cpp.h

```
#include "constants.h"
```

my_cpp.cpp

```
#include "my_cpp.h"

double A[x];
```

So here, I would get an error stating that x is not an integer constant. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: For the C++ compiler to see a `const` variable as a compile-time constant, it needs to see the full definition (including the initialization). If it can't see that then the variable is a run-time constant and can't be used as an array size.

Comment: @jdhabez:  Is a compiler *error message* involved?  If not, do the modules link successfully?   (Maybe `I would get an error`... actually means `I get an error`?)

Comment: here's some code that shows using a const int is fine - even with VLAs disabled: https://godbolt.org/z/dyq1BT

Comment: This is a pure C++ question. A `const int` in *C* is not an integer constant expression and you cannot use it for a *static array dimension* whatsoever.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to the question asked, but still I think important is to note is that C or C++ source code files are normally not called `scripts`, and this can be confusing.

Comment: @xaxxon Isn't the `int const x` in your example also a compile-time constant even though you didn't explicitly declare it `constexpr`?

Comment: Nitpick: C++ is a compiled language, not a interpreted scripting language. So, you should not refer to your source files as "scripts", since they are not. They are source files that will be compiled into executable code. Not scripts that will be interpreted.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Nitpick: C++ is neither compiled nor interpreted language. Standard doesn't specify this, and C++ script engines do exist, although ones I've heard of do not implement full C++ standard.

Comment: @SergeyA True. Point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't put definition of `x` in the header file, so it is not a core constant expression.

Easiest way to fix would be to use `const int x = 5;` in your header file. Alternatively, you can use enum: `enum { x = 5; }` - this gives you true prvalue, pretty much like the literal `5` itself.

More information on what is a constant expression in C++ (and array indexes need to be constant expressions in C++) can be found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression

Comment: @SergeyA Hmm, right so I can get it to work if I did that in the CPP header file. However, I would like to have a single place where that value is hard coded rather than looking for it in multiple files whenever that value gets changed.

Comment: Isn't putting `const int x = 5;` in the header an ODR violation waiting to happen?

Comment: @jdhabez how do you mean? If it is `const`, it will not be changed anywhere, this is the whole point.

Comment: @MilesBudnek, not unless it is ODR-used, but I didn't want to open this whole can of worms with ODR usage, and since OP didn't ask about it, preferred to talk about it.

Comment: @SergeyA, I don't mean the value changing while its being used, but if I wanted to change the value from 5 to 10 and recompile I would need to locate every location where that value gets initialized and assigned.

Comment: @jdhabez again not clear why would you want to locate. If you want to change the value, you go ahead and change it in the header, and your build system recompiles all source files which use this header.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes but I would need to change that value at multiple locations rather than at a single location..... The above is a simple example.. my actual project is pretty large and this particular integer may change through design iterations. It seems like its a bug waiting to happen if I have the value defined in multiple locations and need to edit each one in order to recompile.

Comment: @SergeyA I might. But ... somewhere I got that `const` qualified variables aren't compile-time constants. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: @jdhabez How is that value at multiple locations? You cannot initialize the same variable twice.

Comment: @Quimby I have it initialized in a C script that is dedicated for global constants. The const integers are stored there. I am being told that i will not be able to use those in order to declare array dimmensions, so now I need to create a new const int that holds the same value as the const int in my C constants script in order to get used in my CPP scripts.... that means I have two hardcoded variables to change (if a change is needed) rather than just having one hard coded variable to change in my C constants code.

Comment: @jdhabez:  Why is it important to have a `const int`?  Is there an advantage over having the constant value in an `enum` or even `#define`?

Comment: @jdhabez No, what's being suggested is to _move_ the definition from constants.c to constants.h, not duplicate it.

Comment: @jdhabez Thank you for the explanation. The bottom line is that during compilation of `my_cpp.cpp` object file the value must be known to the compiler. So it must be in a header.

Comment: @jdhabez but why does it have to be in this other file? Why can't you simply have it in the header? On any rate, `enum` option is still available, although I would argue against using `define`.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Ah.. ok I can try that.

Comment: @SergeyA Its just that 80% of the project has been completed at this point and I've been using it this way.. I am worried that I'll fudge things up if I make this sort of change. It is my first large C/C++ project  ever, and my inexperience is evident.